# Undefined sequence error

Tags: undefined

I installed winedit 3 and miktex and whenever I run the program there is 
undefined control sequence

```
 <argument> \g__prg_map_int"
```

error. What should I do? the line causing the error is:

```
\MakeSPathList{calligraphy pen copperplate}{\l__cal_tmpa_tl}
```

Comment: Probably 'Update your installation', but without a code example it's hard to be sure

Comment: You say 'whenever I run the program'. WHich program are you talking about? How do you start it? What else is shown as output? Where is the error shown? What did you use as input?

Comment: The variable `\g__prg_map_int` was recently renamed `\g_kernel_prg_map_int`. Probably you didn't update everything on your TeX system, or some code you use is abusing internal variables. Please, add a minimal example of code that produces the error.

Comment: The `spath3` package is indeed abusing `\g__prg_map_int` and should be rewritten not to use kernel internals.

Comment: I checked the suggested link and entered the codes but it asks for the file name